# Converting PHP code into JS

Tags: php, javascript

I have this PHP code -

```
 <?php
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++) {
  $array=array();
  $array[$i]=54*$i;

  $arr=array($array[$i].",");

  foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo $value;
  }
}
?>
```

I tried with:

```
var i;
for(i=1;i<=1000;i++) {
  var array = new Array();
  array[i] = 54*i;
  var arr = new Array();
  arr.push(array[i]+",");
}
alert(arr)
```

But it doesn't work.
Where's the mistake?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What output did you get? What output did you expect?

Comment: When you do the array output outside the `for` loop (as you do in your JavaScript example), you will only get the last array as it’s re-initiated with each iteration.

Comment: don't think the php will do what you want either, all it does is echo ($i*54).','; each time, but in a really convoluted way for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild stab.. because the PHP code while it may produce the expected output, is actually 'wrong' (wrong on the basis that you may expect the array to hold all those values, and it doesn't).

so here's the php (fixed).

```
<?php
$a = array();
$stringVersion = '';
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++) {
  $a[$i] = 54*$i;
  $stringVersion .= $a[$i] . ',';
}
echo $stringVersion;
```

and here's a JS alternative

```
var a = [];
var stringVersion = '';
for(var i=1;i<=1000; i++) {
  a[i] = 54*i;
  stringVersion += a[i] + ',';
}
alert(stringVersion);
```

Comment: I'd rather use `stringVersion = implode(',', $a);` after the iteration.

Comment: likewise re implode, I had it like that but the js version looked different then and didn't match, so aligned them :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var array = new Array(1000);
for(var i=1;i<=1000;i++) { 
    array[i] = 54*i; 
} 
alert(array[1000]) ;
```

Just a few "pointers" (pun unintended);

1. You sure don't want all 1000 calls to be echoed to messageboxes - I only display the last (1000 * 54) to the user - clicking Ok 1000 times ...
2. You don't push anything into an array like Php code. In this case I "define" the arraylength to 1000, but creating an array without the lenght does work to. Just "add" items with arrayName[indexToBeCreated] et voila.
3. Loop variables don't need to be defined before the loop, just define them inside the loop (for (var i blabla...

Hope it helps